# PYTHON - Stop executing function/def

Tags: python, if-statement

```
a = 0

if (a==0):
  print "a==0"


print "hello"
```

I have many code where the print "hello" is, and I can't put an else and just TAB everything. Is there anything that can stop executing the function or something?

Comment: have you used 'break' ?

Comment: If you want a function to return, `return`.  (This returns the same value a function does when it "falls off the end", i.e., `None`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python programs, it's much better to use spaces to tabs.  If you can, configure your IDE to do this.  The parenthesis surrounding `(a==0)` are superfluous.

```
a= 0
if a == 0 :
    print "a==0"
print "hello"
```

The quickest way to stop a function's execution is instruction `return` .

Comment: Does not answer the question. -1

Comment: @PlatinumAzure  Of course it does.

Comment: Didn't see the last part at the time I wrote my comment. Removed -1. That said you wasted a lot of space on irrelevant information.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure  It's hard to understand OP's question.  Just tried to be useful and nice to him/her.  He/she's obviously a non-native English speaker (as I am not either), or was sailing very rough waters.